# SQL Server query: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. They have a join on `TableA.refID = TableB.SomeID`, then some other columns (`TableA.time`, `TableB.kind`).

I would like make a query, order by time a and group them by type.

This is the query I use (modified for a best showcase)

```
SELECT  
   *, TableA.time AS B, TableB.type AS A
FROM       
   TableB  
INNER JOIN
   TableB ON TableB.SomeID = TableA.refID
ORDER BY 
   B
GROUP BY 
   TableB.type
```

I get this exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.

How should I correct it?

Comment: First u should use group by and then order by

Comment: I suspect you're saying `GROUP` when in fact you're just looking for a secondary sort - so it's probably either `ORDER BY B,TableB.Type` or `ORDER BY TableB.Type,B` that you're looking for. `GROUP` is used to condense multiple rows down into a single row, and usually to compute aggregates from those multiple rows, but you're not showing any attempts to aggregate here. If it's not a secondary sort you're attempting, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: One other note nobody else mentioned is you dont have TableA in your FROM clause, but have two instances of TableB... change the ONE of them, otherwise once group by is ok, will fail for the alias/table not found.

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  *, TableA.time AS B, TableB.type AS A
FROM       TableB INNER JOIN
                  TableB ON TableB.SomeID = TableA.refID
GROUP BY TableB.type
ORDER BY B
```

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT..
FROM...
WHERE...
GROUP BY..
ORDER BY..
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things wrong with your query:

1. You have a group by after an order by. You can't order and then group you order grouped results
2. You're selecting `*` and grouping, that won't work.
3. You're grouping on `TableB.type` but `TableA.time` is not an aggregate so it either needs to be part of a group or an aggregate.

Here is an example of what your procedure should look like:

```
SELECT  
    TableA.time AS B, TableB.type AS A
FROM
    TableB 
INNER JOIN
    TableB ON TableB.SomeID = TableA.refID
GROUP BY 
    TableB.type, TableA.time
ORDER BY 
    TableA.time
```

OR

```
SELECT  Max(TableA.time) AS B, TableB.type AS A
FROM       TableB INNER JOIN
                  TableB ON TableB.SomeID = TableA.refID

GROUP BY TableB.type
ORDER BY Max(TableA.time)
```

Comment: Also, the query should probably select from `TableA` and join to `TableB` instead of using `TableB` twice ....